# return select from view, update one column postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a view.  I want a function which returns rows from the view; however, I need to change one value in each of the rows I return.

I can do this using select and writing all the field names in the select clause and listing all the values including the one I change, but this makes the code very obscure.

Seems like I want a very light weight temporary table.  I want to write something like:

```
update { select * from myView where f(row,x,y) }
     set column = y
```

where x and y are arguments to my function, column is a column name from myView, and f is another function.

Is there something like this I can write?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some pointers:

- You can do this with another view in which you have to list all your columns separately: `CREATE VIEW myViewModified AS SELECT y AS column, ... FROM myView;` and after that you can use `SELECT * FROM myViewModified WHERE f(row,x,y);`
- You could also write `SELECT y AS column1modified, * FROM myView;` in the code and use the column1modified. That way you can use the asterisk-symbol.
- Listing all the values might make the code obscure but if you drive the code through [Poor SQL](http://poorsql.com/) you can make it look quite clean (it also helps if you are accustomed to reading SQL queries).
- [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3639861/1288184)